# Unexpected Behavior Working in Prime Order Subgroup with Java BigInteger Class

Tags: group-theory, searchable-encryption

I'm implementing a searchable symmetric encryption scheme, developed by others, for my own personal enrichment.  The original research is located at the link:  https://eprint.iacr.org/2013/169.  I'm using the BigInteger class in Java to perform the group operations.  The scheme splits the exponentiation between the client and the server so as to prevent information leakage to the server.  I generate a value `xtag`, as illustrated below:

```
BigInteger exp = z.multiply(ithTermDigest).multiply(y).mod(p); // This works as expected
BigInteger xtag = g.modPow(exp, p); // This works as expected
```

`z` is a pseudorandom element of prime order subgroup Zp.
`ithTermDigest` is a pseudorandom element of prime order subgroup Zp.
`y` is the modular inverse of `z` multiplied by a a pseudorandom element of prime order subgroup Zp, and is used as a "blinding factor" for the server.
`g` is a generator of the group.

The above code works as expected.  The value z and it's inverse in y cancel out to leave `ithTermDigest` * `(the pseudorandom element of the group)`, and the correct value of `xtag` results.

What is vexing me is that the below code does not generate the same value for `xtag`:

```
//The client will compute this part and send xtoken to the server
BigInteger exp = z.multiply(ithTermDigest).mod(p);
BigInteger xtoken = g.modPow(exp, p);

//The server will compute this part using blinding factor y.
BigInteger xtag = xtoken.modPow(y, p);
```

The value for `xtag` does not mirror the previous result.  I would expect g<sup>ab</sup> to provide the same result as (g<sup>a</sup>)<sup>b</sup>.  Are my expectations ill-founded?  Is there anything obviously wrong? I don't pretend to be a mathematician or a cryptographer.  Please point me to an appropriate forum if this isn't.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I would expect $g^{ab}$ to provide the same result as $(g^a)^b$.

They are; however that's not what you're computing.

Instead, you're computing $g^{ab \bmod p}$; that's not the same.

If, instead, you computed $g^{ab \bmod p-1}$, then you'd be good; that's because $g^x \equiv g^{x \bmod p-1} \pmod p$ (Fermat's little theorem).

Comment: Many thanks for your quick response.  I'll try to make the changes this weekend and circle back to close the loop.